# HtmlUnit cannot render Google Maps

Tags: java, google-maps, htmlunit

This code below cannot render Google Maps:

```
String completeUrl = "https://www.google.com.ph/maps/search/wallmart";
System.out.println(completeUrl);
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController(){
    @Override
    public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async) {
        return true;
    }
});
//webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(20000);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(completeUrl);
```

What we get is a HTML with this code fragment:

```
<a class="no-script-help-link" href="//support.google.com/maps/?hl=en&amp;authuser=0&amp;p=no_javascript" target="_blank"> Enable JavaScript to see Google Maps. </a>
```

What can be wrong in this code? Since it has *20 seconds* wait for Javascript already.

Answer (score 1):

Many things:

1. use the latest snapshot build
2. start with the default configuration; it makes no sense to configure many options if you have no special use for
3. setAjaxController - do not use this if there is no need
4. as reported many times before here: waitForBackgroundJavaScript is not an option, you have to call it AFTER e.g. getPage or click

Have done a local test and got some js errors in the log. If you like to get this errors fixed, please try to isolate a minimal case (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html) and report to the HtmlUnit bug tracker.